# Routing with Google Maps on Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am building an Android App and I'd like to imlement the Google Maps Api to enables Routing from Point A to B. So far, I have managed to implement the Google maps and display it on the app, If anybody can explain how do to add "directions", that would be great.

Comment: where is your code? show your effort.....

Answer (score 1):

Using Intent

```
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" +sourcelat+","+sourcelon+"&daddr="+destlat+","+destlon;
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

And another using code Download [sourcecode](http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?t8idm6zapac7cal)

Comment: If you want to put it on your own map implementation your out of luck. This is the current only supported way for google maps. Alternatively look into osmdroid or similar.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/j2memaprouteprovider/source/browse/trunk/J2MEMapRouteAndroidEx/?r=8

Comment: download here complete code http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?t8idm6zapac7cal